# Making intlTelInput and Jquery mask plugins to work together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to add the "mask" feature (from [jquery mask plugin](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)) to the [intlTelInput](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input) plugin.
 This way, the user input will be "forced" to have the number phone pattern according to the country he selected.

Here is my code for now (which you should be able to run easily as I added online ressources):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Hello</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/11.0.14/css/intlTelInput.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/11.0.14/js/utils.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/11.0.14/js/intlTelInput.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.11/jquery.mask.js"></script>

</head>


<body>

      <form action="" method="POST" onsubmit="return submitForm(this);">

            <input type="tel"name ="phone1" id="phone1" value="<?php echo $phone1;?>">

            <input type="tel" class="hide" id="hiden">

            <button type="submit">Validate</button>

      </form>


</body>



<script>

/* INITIALIZE BOTH INPUTS WITH THE intlTelInput FEATURE*/

$("#phone1").intlTelInput({
  initialCountry: "us",
  separateDialCode: true,
  preferredCountries: ["fr", "us", "gb"],
  geoIpLookup: function(callback) {
    $.get('https://ipinfo.io', function() {}, "jsonp").always(function(resp) {
      var countryCode = (resp && resp.country) ? resp.country : "";
      callback(countryCode);
    });
  },
  utilsScript: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/11.0.14/js/utils.js"
});


$("#hiden").intlTelInput({
  initialCountry: "us",
  dropdownContainer: 'body',
  utilsScript: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/11.0.14/js/utils.js"
});



/* ADD A MASK IN PHONE1 INPUT (when document ready and when changing flag) FOR A BETTER USER EXPERIENCE */

var mask1 = $("#phone1").attr('placeholder').replace(/[0-9]/g, 0);

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#phone1').mask(mask1)});

$("#phone1").on("countrychange", function(e, countryData) {
  $("#phone1").val('');
  var mask1 = $("#phone1").attr('placeholder').replace(/[0-9]/g, 0);
  $('#phone1').mask(mask1);
});


/*ON SUBMIT...*/

function submitForm(oFormElement)
  {


  document.getElementById("hiden").value = $("#phone1").val().replace(/\s+/g, ''); // REMOVE ALL THE SPACES OF PHONE1 VALUE
                                                                                   // PUT THE RESULT IN HIDEN INPUT 
                                                                                   // AND TEST THIS LATTER TO SEE IF IT FITS WITH
                                                                                   // the intlTelInput NUMBER FORMAT

  //alert($("#hiden").val());


   // AND IT WILL DISPLAY OK
  if($("#hiden").intlTelInput("isValidNumber")==true){  
    alert("OK");
    return true;
  }
  else{
    alert("NOT OK");
    return false;
  }

}


</script>
```

The problem here, is that I can't remove the flags dropdown of the hidden field, as you can see:

[image]

I tried to add an option called **dropdownContainer** to the initialization of the hidden field. It says in the [intltelinput](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input)  doc that this option with the value 'body' should place the flag dropdown next to the container (in this case: 'body') and if this container has `overflow: hidden` then the flag would be actually hidden.

But as you can see, it does not work.

Thank you for your attention.

**p.s:**

1. If you change the flag of the "phone1" input, you will have to change the "initialCountry" value manually for the "hiden" input. (I will fix this later).
2. I already looked for a plugin with both features (from **jquery mask** and **intlTellInput**), and I did not find, but if you know one, please tell me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could select the input element with jquery, and hide its parent. Works in my example:

Code required: `$('input.hide').parent().hide();`

**Please note** you will probably need a better class then `hide` because using my exact method will cause side-effects if you hide other input fields. Try a class like `hide-parent` instead. I've just used this because it works in your example.

Example:

```js
/* INITIALIZE BOTH INPUTS WITH THE intlTelInput FEATURE*/

$("#phone1").intlTelInput({
    initialCountry: "us",
    separateDialCode: true,
    preferredCountries: ["fr", "us", "gb"],
    geoIpLookup: function (callback) {
        $.get('https://ipinfo.io', function () {
        }, "jsonp").always(function (resp) {
            var countryCode = (resp && resp.country) ? resp.country : "";
            callback(countryCode);
        });
    },
    utilsScript: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/11.0.14/js/utils.js"
});


$("#hiden").intlTelInput({
    initialCountry: "us",
    dropdownContainer: 'body',
    utilsScript: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/11.0.14/js/utils.js"
});


/* ADD A MASK IN PHONE1 INPUT (when document ready and when changing flag) FOR A BETTER USER EXPERIENCE */

var mask1 = $("#phone1").attr('placeholder').replace(/[0-9]/g, 0);

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#phone1').mask(mask1)
});

$("#phone1").on("countrychange", function (e, countryData) {
    $("#phone1").val('');
    var mask1 = $("#phone1").attr('placeholder').replace(/[0-9]/g, 0);
    $('#phone1').mask(mask1);
});


/*ON SUBMIT...*/

function submitForm(oFormElement) {


    document.getElementById("hiden").value = $("#phone1").val().replace(/\s+/g, ''); // REMOVE ALL THE SPACES OF PHONE1 VALUE
                                                                                     // PUT THE RESULT IN HIDEN INPUT 
                                                                                     // AND TEST THIS LATTER TO SEE IF IT FITS WITH
                                                                                     // the intlTelInput NUMBER FORMAT

    //alert($("#hiden").val());


    // AND IT WILL DISPLAY OK
    if ($("#hiden").intlTelInput("isValidNumber") == true) {
        alert("OK");
        return true;
    }
    else {
        alert("NOT OK");
        return false;
    }

}

$('input.hide').parent().hide();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/11.0.14/css/intlTelInput.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/11.0.14/js/utils.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/11.0.14/js/intlTelInput.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.11/jquery.mask.js"></script>


<form action="" method="POST" onsubmit="return submitForm(this);">

    <input type="tel"name ="phone1" id="phone1" value="<?php echo $phone1;?>">

    <input type="tel" class="hide" id="hiden">

    <button type="submit">Validate</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Excellent :) Thanks!

Comment: It helped but there is one problem. If you change country to anyone and then select US. The format is not correct.

Answer (score 11):

It is not professional to add a hidden input manually to apply this feature, especially when using plugins like this one which includes a lot of APIs and methods.

After studying the documentation of the `intl-tel-input` (https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input) and `utils.js`  (https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input/wiki/utils.js), the solution can be like this:

Hook a callback function to the `countrychange` event to apply the mask based on the selected country.

**Make sure to place this JS snippet in the footer or at least after the HTML input we're targeting.**

```js
// Make sure to place this snippet in the footer or at least after
// the HTML input we're targeting.

$(document).ready(function() {
  var phoneInputID = "#phone";
  var input = document.querySelector(phoneInputID);
  var iti = window.intlTelInput(input, {
    // allowDropdown: false,
    // autoHideDialCode: false,
    // autoPlaceholder: "off",
    // dropdownContainer: document.body,
    // excludeCountries: ["us"],
    formatOnDisplay: true,
    // geoIpLookup: function(callback) {
    //   $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function() {}, "jsonp").always(function(resp) {
    //     var countryCode = (resp && resp.country) ? resp.country : "";
    //     callback(countryCode);
    //   });
    // },
    hiddenInput: "full_number",
    // initialCountry: "auto",
    // localizedCountries: { 'de': 'Deutschland' },
    // nationalMode: false,
    // onlyCountries: ['us', 'gb', 'ch', 'ca', 'do'],
    // placeholderNumberType: "MOBILE",
    preferredCountries: ['es'],
    // separateDialCode: true,
    utilsScript: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/11.0.14/js/utils.js"
  });


  $(phoneInputID).on("countrychange", function(event) {

    // Get the selected country data to know which country is selected.
    var selectedCountryData = iti.getSelectedCountryData();

    // Get an example number for the selected country to use as placeholder.
    newPlaceholder = intlTelInputUtils.getExampleNumber(selectedCountryData.iso2, true, intlTelInputUtils.numberFormat.INTERNATIONAL),

      // Reset the phone number input.
      iti.setNumber("");

    // Convert placeholder as exploitable mask by replacing all 1-9 numbers with 0s
    mask = newPlaceholder.replace(/[1-9]/g, "0");

    // Apply the new mask for the input
    $(this).mask(mask);
  });


  // When the plugin loads for the first time, we have to trigger the "countrychange" event manually, 
  // but after making sure that the plugin is fully loaded by associating handler to the promise of the 
  // plugin instance.

  iti.promise.then(function() {
    $(phoneInputID).trigger("countrychange");
  });

});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.12/js/intlTelInput.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.11/jquery.mask.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/17.0.12/css/intlTelInput.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think this is by far the best solution and should be marked as the accepted answer. 

One question though, @Ahmed El-Atab, when I add the geoIpLookup in the ini object, I get an error saying intlTelInputUtils is undefined. Any idea why this is?

Comment: @GustavVingtoft Can you please share the code of initializing the object?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my (lighter) jQuery take at it:

```
<label for="telephone">Téléphone</label>
<input id="telephone" name="telephone" type="tel">
```

```
$('#telephone').on('focus', function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        // Get active country's phone number format from input placeholder attribute
        activePlaceholder = $this.attr('placeholder'),
        // Convert placeholder as exploitable mask by replacing all 1-9 numbers with 0s
        newMask = activePlaceholder.replace(/[1-9]/g, "0");
        // console.log(activePlaceholder + ' => ' + newMask);

    // Init new mask for focused input
    $this.mask(newMask);
});
```

No need to double-input. Works everytime you select a new country.

Comment: It helped but there is one problem. If you change country to anyone and then select US. The format is not correct